# Oracle & Powershell different behaviour in batch file

Tags: windows, oracle, powershell, batch-file

I have built a script that connects to an Oracle database and proceed to some various export.

It works perfectly when I **launch powershell.exe from Windows start menu** and run the script as follows:

```
.\OracleConnect
```

But, when I try to automatize **the exact same script** by launching it from a batch, I'm getting an error message:

"The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception"

As I said the script is identical in both case.

My .bat file is as follows:

```
    set path=%~dp0
    set file=OracleConnect.ps1
    C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass %file%
```

I've also tried with the alternative powershell.exe path:

```
    C:\Windows\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass %file%
```

Without any success.

Here is my full script:

```
$scriptpath = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
Set-Location $scriptpath
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($scriptpath + "\Oracle.DataAccess.dll")
$logpath = $scriptpath + "\Export.txt" 

$connectionpath = read-host 'connection file [optional]'
if($connectionpath)
{
    $connectionstring = get-content $connectionpath
}
else
{
    $server = read-host 'host name'
    $user = read-host 'user name'
    $pass = read-host 'password'
    $database = read-host 'service'
    $connectionstring = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=$server)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=$database)));User Id=$user;Password=$pass;"
}

$echoon = read-host 'echo on (y - n) [default off]'

function global:get-result($query)
{
    $oracleconnection = new-object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
    $oracleconnection.connectionstring = $connectionstring
    $oracleconnection.Open()
    $oraclecommand = $oracleconnection.CreateCommand()
    $oraclecommand.CommandText = $query
    $reader = $oraclecommand.ExecuteReader()

    $writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($logpath)

    $counter = 0
    write-output ""
    while ($reader.Read()) 
    {
        $columns = ""
        $columnslog = ""
        $tab = "" 
        $tablog = "" 
        if($counter -eq 0)
        {
            for ($i= 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++) 
            {
                $columns = $columns + " | " + $reader.GetName($i)
                $columnslog = $columnslog + "`t" + $reader.GetName($i).ToUpper()
            }
            $writer.WriteLine($columnslog)

            if($echoon -eq "y")
            {
                write-output $columns
                write-output ""
            }
        }

        for ($i= 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++) 
        {
            $tab = $tab + " | " + $reader.GetValue($i).ToString()
            $tablog = $tablog + "`t" + $reader.GetValue($i).ToString()
        }

        $writer.WriteLine($tablog)

        if($echoon -eq "y")
        {
            write-output $tab 
            write-output ""
        }

        $counter = $counter + 1
    }

    $oracleconnection.Close()
    $writer.Close()
}

function global:update-query($query)
{
    $oracleconnection = new-object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
    $oracleconnection.connectionstring = $connectionstring
    $oracleconnection.Open()
    $oraclecommand = $oracleconnection.CreateCommand()
    $oraclecommand.CommandText = $query
    $reader = $oraclecommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
}

function global:readscript($path)
{
    $inenc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF7
    $reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($path, $inenc)
    $finalquery = ""

    while ($line = $reader.ReadLine())
    {
        $finalquery += $line
    }
    $reader.close()

    return $finalquery
}

write-output "Enter query or type 'exit' to quit..."
while($true)
{
    $value = read-host " "
    if($value -eq "exit")
    {
        $save = read-host "Save connection ? [Y:yes N:no]"
        if($save.ToLower() -eq "y")
        {
            $path = read-host "Connection path"
            if(test-path $path)
            {
                rm $path
            }
            new-item -type file -force $path
            $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $path
            $writer.WriteLine($connectionstring)
            $writer.Close()
        }
        else
        {

        }
        return
    }
    else 
    {
        if($value.Tolower().EndsWith(".sql") -eq $false)
        {
            if ($value.ToLower().StartsWith("select") -or $value.ToLower().StartsWith("show"))
            {
                get-result($value)
            }
            else
            {
                update-query($value)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $scriptquery = readscript $value
            if ($scriptquery.ToLower().StartsWith("select") -or $scriptquery.ToLower().StartsWith("show"))
            {
                get-result($scriptquery)
            }
            else
            {
                update-query($scriptquery)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

I've now tried to catch the exception adding a try catch instruction here:

```
try 
{
    $oracleconnection = new-object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
}
catch
{
     write-host $_.Exception.ToString()
}
```

And I'm getting this message:
**Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client**

I still don't understand how this can be an issue with the version of Oracle since it works fine when I run it from a powershell window.

Comment: Show your powershell script.

Comment: Updated with script.

Comment: Is `%ORACLE_HOME%` the same in both situations?

Comment: how can I verify that ?  I added echo %ORACLE_HOME% but it doesn't  seem to be the correct command

Comment: Is you oracle library "oci.dll" in your path? Output PATH in PS: $env:PATH